# How to access tools from the tools panel in blender 2.8

Tags: interface

One of the first changes I noticed in blender 2.8 was that this panel:

[image: blender 2.79 tools panel]

was gone, along with all of the tools that where in it, some of the most useful of which for me where the physics tools. Is there any way to bring it back, or if not, where did all of the tools on it go (ex. I still can't find the copy physics from active)? I'm not really expecting someone to tell me about every single tool, but just generally if they were relocated to somewhere specific or just thrown all over the new interface.

Comment: It's on the horizontal bar above the main window.

Comment: as Yvain said, in the horizontal menu bar > Object > Rigid Body

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for[image]

Good Luck

Comment: Thank you, this does solve part of the problem, but what I really wanted to know was where all of tools went in general. Would they all also be hidden somewhere in the menu bar, or otherwise?

Comment: As you can see on the image, must of the tools are there, you can also try with F3 or the Space bar to search the tools, depending on your keyboard layout